# how to configure proper video-player video output for Unichrome-Pro card?

Tags: xorg, video-player, via, openchrome

After upgrade to 12.04.1 from 10.04, all video players yield blank screen.
VLC has been made to show video properly by setting its video output to "X11 (XCB)" while it was set to "XVideo (XCB)" by default.
How can I do the same with Totem and Pitivi?
Video card is "VIA S3 Unichrome Pro"